# How to efficiently insert multiple copy-constructible but not copy-assignable elements in a vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a type `X`, which is copy-constructible but not copy assignable

```cpp
struct X {
    X();
    X(const X&);
    X& operator=(const X&) = delete; // !!
    X(X&&) noexcept;
    X& operator=(X&&) noexcept;
    int data = 54;
};
```

I have two vectors of 'X': `a` and `b` and I want to insert all the contents of `b` at the front of `a`:

```cpp
void add_to_front(std::vector<X>& a, const std::vector<X>& b) {
    a.insert(a.begin(), b.begin(), b.end());
}
```

This compiles and works as expected on msvc but fails to compile on clang and gcc. I'm guessing due to poor implementations of libc++ and libstdc++ which need something to compile even though it will never get called (or, worse yet, it will get called!?).

I could write a manual loop to `emplace` elements of `b` into `a` which will produce a correct result, but the complexity of this is a*b instead of a+b, as each call to `emplace` will shift all elements of `a` over and over again.

So is there an efficient way to do it?

[Live demo can be found here](https://godbolt.org/z/K1WT8n)

Comment: It works with a little trick: [**Live Demo on Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/3n5P9M)

Comment: @Scheff, looks like an answer.

Comment: That's still not as efficient as insert as it needs to allocate temporary additional memory for the size of b (even if we disregard the additional b.size() move ctor calls which might not be trivial)

Comment: Though, instead of add to front I would consider to append the data and then move the whole result vector into the original instance if urgently required. Moving individual elements may come to a price but moving a whole vector is probably very cheap.

Comment: Ah... Actually I think this may be the answer! Create a vector, reserve a+b items. Copy items of b. Move items of a at the back. Move new vector into a. Add this and I'll accept it as an answer. It's still slightly worse than insert in case a's capacity DID have enough room to store a+b elements, but it's better than the temporary in terms of ctor calls

Comment: That must be as efficient as `x.insert(x.end()...` I can't think of any magic insert might do to make it faster... I guess a times ++end instead of 1 time end+=a. That's nothing

Comment: I'm not that sure anymore as well. (Maybe, it was a reflex that inserting at the beginning of a `std::vector` just feels uncomfortable to me.)

Comment: This is what I ended with: [**Fiddling on Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/3vr6Ko). Guessing in head what is copied how often, I don't see a real advantage anymore. :-( (Though, I didn't check seriously.) I give up...

Comment: @Scheff I [fiddled with your fiddle](https://godbolt.org/z/fvhKa1) to optimize it and that's what I intend to use until the library authors fix it

Comment: You still could add an `#ifdef _MSC_VER` and use the original version on MSVC. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I must admit that I'm not quite sure whether the *poor implementations of libc++ and libstdc++* are the issue. Though, I found a quite simple way to circumvent OPs issue:

```
#include <vector>

struct X {
    X() = default;
    X(const X&) = default;
    X& operator=(const X&) = delete; // !!
    X(X&&) noexcept = default;
    X& operator=(X&&) noexcept = default;
    int data = 54;
};

void add_to_front(std::vector<X>& a, const std::vector<X>& b) {
    std::vector<X> b_(b);
    a.insert(a.begin(), std::make_move_iterator(b_.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(b_.end()));
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<X> a, b;
  add_to_front(a, b);
}
```

This is accepted by

- clang 11.0.0 `-std=c++11 -O2`
- gcc 9.2 `-std=c++11 -O2`
- msvc 19.28 `/std:c++14 /O2`

[**Live Demo on Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/arz3j7)

---

[@Evg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65489039/how-to-efficiently-insert-multiple-copy-constructible-but-not-copy-assignable-el/65489262#comment115782045_65489262) had a look into the
[**Type requirements for std::vector::insert()**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert#Parameters)

In OPs case it's this overload:

> ```
> template< class InputIt >
> iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );
> ```

with

> - T must meet the requirements of EmplaceConstructible in order to use overload (4,5).
> - T must meet the requirements of MoveAssignable and MoveInsertable in order to use overload (4). required only if InputIt satisfies LegacyInputIterator but not LegacyForwardIterator.

This should be granted by OPs `struct X`.

So, to me, it looks like OP is right with the complaints.

Comment: Thanks! While this is much better than a*b, I'm not going to accept is an answer, as it's still not as efficient as insert. Compared to insert it additionally requires a temporary allocation and b.size() move ctor calls. I fear a custom vector implementation is the only solution here...

Comment: Copy assignability is not listed among type requirements [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert#Parameters). So it looks like an implementation bug.

Comment: I reported at llvm's bug tracker: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48619